# tensorflow/keras "An op outside of the function building code is being passed a 'Graph' Tensor"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a newcomer to Tensorflow/Keras, and I've been following along with the book Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow. Chapter 12 deals with customizing Tensorflow, and following along with the associated notebook ([here](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/12_custom_models_and_training_with_tensorflow.ipynb)) I've hit the following custom model:

```py
class ReconstructingRegressor(keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hidden = [keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="selu",
                                          kernel_initializer="lecun_normal")
                       for _ in range(5)]
        self.out = keras.layers.Dense(output_dim)

    def build(self, batch_input_shape):
        n_inputs = batch_input_shape[-1]
        self.reconstruct = keras.layers.Dense(n_inputs)
        super().build(batch_input_shape)
        
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        Z = inputs
        for layer in self.hidden:
            Z = layer(Z)
        reconstruction = self.reconstruct(Z)

        recon_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(reconstruction - inputs))        
        self.add_loss(0.05 * recon_loss)

        return self.out(Z)
```

When I go to train using this model, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: mul:0
```

The problem is `self.add_loss(0.05 * recon_loss)`; after commenting that out everything runs fine. Presumably `recon_loss` is the `"Graph" tensor` and `self.add_loss()` is the `op outside of the function building code`, but -- if that applies to `add_loss()` -- I don't know how I would add to the loss from within `call()`.

Full disclosure: I'm using Tensorflow 2.3 when the book was written with 2.1 in mind, so I'm not really following instructions. That said, I'm really curious how to fix this and at my current level of knowledge I feel essentially powerless. It *seems* like it should work -- how else to add to the loss function? Any help would be appreciated here.

Full example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

housing = fetch_california_housing()
X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(
    housing.data, housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), random_state=42)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(
    X_train_full, y_train_full, random_state=42)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_valid_scaled = scaler.transform(X_valid)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

class ReconstructingRegressor(keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hidden = [keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="selu",
                                          kernel_initializer="lecun_normal")
                       for _ in range(5)]
        self.out = keras.layers.Dense(output_dim)

    def build(self, batch_input_shape):
        n_inputs = batch_input_shape[-1]
        self.reconstruct = keras.layers.Dense(n_inputs)
        super().build(batch_input_shape)
        
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        Z = inputs
        for layer in self.hidden:
            Z = layer(Z)
        reconstruction = self.reconstruct(Z)
        recon_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(reconstruction - inputs))
        
        self.add_loss(0.05 * recon_loss)

        return self.out(Z)

model = ReconstructingRegressor(1, dynamic=True)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="nadam")
history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think it's too late to answer the question... Let me show you what I've tried.

**First, I removed the build function of the custom model.**

```
    def build(self, batch_input_shape):
        n_inputs = batch_input_shape[-1]
        self.reconstruct = keras.layers.Dense(n_inputs)
        super().build(batch_input_shape)
```

**And `run_eagerly = True` when compiling** *OR* **using a custom layer calculating the custom loss worked.**
**For example**, write a custom layer code:

```
class ReconLoss(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, inputs):
    x, reconstruction = inputs
    recon_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(reconstruction - x))

    self.add_loss(0.05 * recon_loss)

    return
```

Then assign an instance of it in `__init__` of the custom model, insert `self.ReconLoss([x, reconstruction])` into call method of the custom model.

Edited colab code : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Hwi6auz2meKvD0ogdDSywb2E4_J1F9S_?usp=sharing

I don't understand still why the error was raised, but this worked for me.

References :

- [Tensorflow 2.1.0 - An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551145/tensorflow-2-1-0-an-op-outside-of-the-function-building-code-is-being-passed-a)
- [Deep Learning with Python code no longer working. "TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271841/deep-learning-with-python-code-no-longer-working-typeerror-an-op-outside-of-t)
- https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/711